# VSCode Jupyter kernel crashes often. Exit message - `The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell.`

Tags: crash, kernel, jupyter, ram, vscode-remote

For quite a while now I have been having a problem when running cells in a `.ipynb` file in VSCode. The issue is that I attempt to run a cell and it returns this error message directly underneath the failing cell `The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.` as shown in the image below:

[image]

Typically, I have noticed this happening with cells that are quite compute intensive. For example, here I was training an `sklearn` model and performing merges of fairly large df's (more than 10000 rows). This led me to believe that it might be related to my laptop which is an HP Envy with 8GB of RAM and I am running the notebooks in WSL2. Additionally, when running the same code on my personal laptop (which is the same model, but with 16GB RAM) the code takes a long time but it runs. The other strange point to make is that sometimes these cells run fine, and sometimes they cause the kernel to crash, but I am not sure why it varies at all.

I haven't been able to find similar questions on SO, and since it I am not getting an out of memory error I think my suspicions might be off. Any help and advice would be hugely appreciated here, happy to provide more info if I have left anything out that would be useful!

This issue has persisted for a while and I have tried a few solutions (all related to using less memory when running these cells) such as shutting down other apps, or running the cells as `.py` files instead. I would have thought that using less memory would allow the cell to urn, since that is what I think the issue is (but not certain that it is). None of these have seemed to work, other than simply running the cell every once in a while until it eventually works.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but can only provide some input from my similar experience. It helps if you can precisely isolate where it is happening. If it's during fitting an estimator, does the crash still happen if you fit with much fewer instances, or using a different solver available for the estimator?  You can view RAM consumption using Windows Task Manager - that can help you spot patterns (RAM might climb suddenly before crashing). Another thing to consider is creating a new conda environment, or even doing a fresh install of WSL2.

Comment: The Jupyter error log might detail which part of the code caused the crash. Other uses might be able to study it and provide more info.